# Conditional Formatting Formula AND Date in Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I need a column to turn red if today's date is 1 day before Ship Date and another column is not marked `Shipped`.

I've tried having the TODAY formula in an off sheet cell and reference it but I don't know how to get the Custom formula in Conditional Formatting to get AND to work correctly. I tried just to highlight if it was just set to "Ordered" but that didn't even work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try custom CF rule.

```
=AND($B1=TODAY()-1,$A1="Shipped")
```

[image]